# own wordpress theme creation from html

Tags: html, wordpress-theming

I am now starting to create a Wordpress theme from HTML. I have an HTML page and I want to create a own word press theme according to HTML page.

What reference do I have to read for starting? Please provide me any link or material for starting creation of my own Wordpress theme development. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting html to a wordpress theme is quite a popular topic and a google search will give you an absolute wealth of information. A good palce to start though is with wordpress own documentation [for theme development.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

Another place to start would be looking at wordpress default theme called Twenty Ten and delving into its code.

When looking for tutorials online make sure they are fairly recent because the wordpress core is updated frequently.

Comment: thanks for help.I integrated many paid theme , but I never created for my own theme.